# JDBC's connection strings with CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

How do I connect to CockroachDB in Java using JDBC, e.g. what are the parameters and format of the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a full example of Cockroach using `jdbc` [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/build-a-java-app-with-cockroachdb.html), but here's the code snippet including the connection string:

```
import java.sql.*;

public static void main(String[] args)...{

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:26257/[your database]?sslmode=disable", "maxroach", "");
```